# Sending the current page HTML source to Spring MVC controller

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC, Following is a method which will take either String or Input Stream from the Request and convert into PDF and write the PDF to the respose.

```
public void generatePDF(RequestDTO requestUIDTO, Map<String, Object> responseMap,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer;
    try {

        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
        document.open();
        //Here I need to get the HTML file as String or InputStream from the request.
        //For now i am getting InputStream, It may be string
        InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, in);
        document.close();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, I don't know how to send the current rendered page as HTML to the server, I tried the following Java script but it is not working, the request itself is not going to the server May be because i am sending a huge file as request parameter.

```
function downloadLoanForm(){
     var params = {};
     params = {
             htmlContent : "htmlContent"
     }
     handleRequest(this, params, 'generatePDF.htm', '');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
     var htmlContent = $('#mainFormId').html();
     $('#htmlContent').val(htmlContent);
});
```

My Question is this, Please let me know a way to send the current rendered HTML code to the Server as either a String (or) Stream.

Here is the Java script code for handleRequest() function,

```
function handleRequest(obj, params, request_url, replacement_element_id,
    error_redirection, function_call_after_response) {


//check if there is any value present for the request url
if(!request_url)
{
    alert('<spring:message code="JS_MSG_PROVIDE_URL_FOR_REQUEST" text=""/>');
    return false;
}

//check if the url is an external url
if(isExternal(request_url) === true)
{
    alert('<spring:message code="JS_MSG_REQUEST_CANNOT_SENT_TO_EXTERNAL_LINK" text=""/>');
    return false;
}

//global variable for making the decision on the page redirect after the error from the server - default value is false
error_redirection       = error_redirection || false;

//variable containing the replacement element id which will be used to place the content after the response from the server
replacement_element_id  = replacement_element_id || false;

//variable to decide whether some manipulation has to be done on the response data from the server
// the response data is being sent to this function along with the replacement element id
function_call_after_response = function_call_after_response || '';

//alert(function_call_after_response+'-here');

//set the replacement element's html values to to be empty before the request is being made so as to ensure that user does not go forward without getting the correct result
if(replacement_element_id)
{
    $('#'+replacement_element_id).html("");
}

//var serializedData = Array();
var counter = 0;

//SETTING THE REQUIRED ELEMENTS VALUES TO AN JSON OBJECT FOR SENDING TO THE SERVER - the elements required for the post is passed as an array in the arguments
var serializedData = {};
$.each(params, function(key, field) {

    if($("#"+key).length > 0) {

        //field = escapeHtml(field);

        var value = $("#"+key).val();
        /*if($('input[name="'+field+'"]').length > 0)
        {
            value = $('input[name="'+field+'"]').val();
        }
        else if($('select[name="'+field+'"]').length > 0)
        {
            value = $('select[name="'+field+'"]').val();
        }
        else if($('textarea[name="'+field+'"]').length > 0)
        {
            value = $('textarea[name="'+field+'"]').val();
        }*/

        value = escapeHtml(value);

        if(value != "")
        {
            counter++;
        }

        //serializedData.field = value;
        serializedData[field] = value;

        /*
        if(counter == 0)
        {
            serializedData = field+'='+value;   
        }
        else
        {
            serializedData += '&'+field+'='+value;  
        }
        counter++;
        */
    }
});

if(counter == 0)
{
    return false;
}

serializedData.csrfToken = $('form > input[name=csrfToken]').val();

//alert($('form > input[name=csrfToken]').val());

if(isExternal(request_url) === false)
{
    $('input[name="'+$(obj).attr('name')+'"]').css('float', 'left');
    $.blockUI({ message: "<h3><img src='images/processing.gif' id='processing_plz_wait' alt='Processing...' title='Processing...' border='0' class='processing_img' /><br/><spring:message code="JS_MSG_PLEASE_WAIT" text=""/></h3>" }); 
    $(".blockOverlay").show();
    $(".blockOverlay").css("opacity", "0.6");
    $(".blockMsg").show();
    $(".blockMsg").css("opacity", "1");

    //setTimeout(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: request_url,
            data: serializedData,
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {

                if(data) {

                    //check for some strings to validate session time out - TODO need proper validation check
                    if(data.contains("<html>") && data.contains("<head>")){

                        document.location.href = 'logout.htm';

                    } else {

                        if(replacement_element_id === false) {
                    alert('<spring:message code="JS_MSG_OPERATION_PERFORMED_SUCCESSFULLY" text=""/>');
                    return false;
                }
                        else {

                    //set the response from the server to the form display element
                    $('#'+replacement_element_id).html(data);

                    setTokenValFrmAjaxResp();

                    $('#'+replacement_element_id).find("form ").append('<input type="hidden" value="'+$('#csrfToken').val()+'" name="csrfToken">');

                    $('form > input[name=csrfToken]').val($('#csrfToken').val());

                    if(function_call_after_response != "")
                    {
                        eval(function_call_after_response);
                    }

                    return false;
                }

                    }
                }
            },

            //ERROR HANDLING AS PER THE RESPONSE FROM THE SERVER - TO DO (some extra layer of error handling to be done)
            error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    alert('<spring:message code="JS_MSG_NOT_ABLE_TO_CONNECT_VERIFY_NETWORK" text=""/>');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    alert('<spring:message code="JS_MSG_REQUEST_PAGE_NOT_FOUND" text=""/>');

                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    alert('<spring:message code="JS_MSG_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR" text=""/>');
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    alert('<spring:message code="JS_MSG_REQUESTED_DATA_PARSE_FAILED" text=""/>');
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    alert('<spring:message code="JS_MSG_TOME_OUT_ERROR" text=""/>');
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    alert('<spring:message code="JS_MSG_AJAX_REQUEST_ABORTED" text=""/>');
                } else {
                    alert('<spring:message code="JS_MSG_UNCAUGHT_ERROR" text=""/>' + jqXHR.responseText);

                    if(error_redirection === true)
                    {
                        //redirect to the corresponding error page
                        document.location.href = '';
                    }
                }

                setTokenValFrmAjaxResp();

                return false;
            }
        });

    //}, 100);
}
```

}

Comment: What does your request mapping for the Controller look like? Can you show us the JavaScript function `handleRequest`?

Comment: As you asked i have updated the question with the method handleRequest.

Comment: A cleaner solution is to simply have the Servlet invoke the required JSP and read the response to a String. See my answer here which has a link to a fully functional working example you can check out and run. This demonstrates how a Servlet can send a response as either HTML or PDF http://stackoverflow.com/a/27533212/1356423

Comment: @AlanHay I tried your solution and it is working. But my JSP file is large and the following line,[String html = customResponse.getOutput();] is bringing only half of the page. How to fix it. Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Try flushing the buffer customResponse.flushBuffer(); before customResponse.getOutput();

Comment: @AlanHay Thanks for your response. Yes I tried it but still it is not working. Please let me know if there is any other way to fix it.

Comment: Assuming the JSP is rendered correctly I am guessing it must be some kind of buffering issue but hard to say. Try customResponse.getWriter().flush(). There's some further discussion here . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318024/res-flushbuffer-vs-res-getoutputstream-flush

Comment: @AlanHay Yes the JSP rendered correctly. I tried using customResponse.getWriter().flush() still no luck

Comment: May  be worth opening a new question posting the code you have written (Servlet and Wrapper). You will maybe get some more input that way.